# Python Tuple Class Memory

Tags: python, list, class, memory, tuples

Why does the use of tuple instead of list in objects below increase memory usage?

```
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof


class myClass(object):
    __slots__ = ('l')
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.l = m

m = range(10)
ob = [myClass(m) for i in xrange(100000)]

print asizeof(ob)
for o in ob:
    o.l = tuple(o.l)
print asizeof(ob)
```

The first has size  64697936

The second has size 200697784

Comment: What's the size difference? Show the output.

Comment: The first has size      64697936

The second has size 200697784

Comment: where did you get `asizeof()` from?

Comment: from pympler.asizeof import asizeof

Comment: So roughly it's about a little more than 3x more space as tuple. I know that tuples are immutable which is different than arrays

Comment: You need to pass `myClass(range(10))` for it to be equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original code, every `myClass` instance points to the same list.

```
>>> ob[0].l.append('foo')
>>> ob[1].l
['foo']
```

In other words: you compared the memory usage of one list to that of 100,000 tuples. Compare it to 100,000 lists instead:

```
for o in ob:
    o.l = list(o.l)
```

with these results:

```
6424936
27224856
```

The original:

```
6424936
20024784
```